Problema de análisis léxico en Latino
Estaba usando Latino para practicar algunas cosas y pensé en hacer un pequeño analizador, pero me tope con que no puedo solventar el error de un tipo de dato.
limpiar()

NUMERO = 0
SUMA = 1
RESTA = 2
MULTIPLICACION = 3
DIVISION = 4
MODULO = 5
POTENCIA = 6
PARENTESIS_IZQ = 7
PARENTESIS_DER = 8
FIN_DE_ARCHIVO = 9
FIN_DE_LINEA = 10
ERROR = 11

caracteres_leidos = 0

automata = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 0, 14, 15],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
]

alfabeto = [
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '^', ' ', '\t', '\n' 
]

TAM_ALFABETO = lista.longitud(alfabeto)
CANTIDAD_DE_ESTADOS = 16

funcion columna(c)
    desde (i = 0; i < TAM_ALFABETO; i++)
        si c == alfabeto[i]
            retorno i
    fin
fin

funcion lexer()
    c = leer()
    estado = 0
    desde (i = 0; i <= cadena.longitud(c); i++)
        caracteres_leidos = i
        estado = automata[estado][columna(c)]
        elegir (estado)
            caso 4:
                retorno NUMERO
            caso 5:
                retorno ERROR
            caso 6:
                retorno PARENTESIS_IZQ
            caso 7:
                retorno PARENTESIS_DER
            caso 8:
                retorno SUMA
            caso 9:
                retorno RESTA
            caso 10:
                retorno MULTIPLICACION
            caso 11:
                retorno DIVISION
            caso 12:
                retorno MODULO
            caso 13:
                retorno POTENCIA
            caso 14:
                retorno FIN_DE_LINEA
            caso 15:
                retorno ERROR
        fin
    fin
    retorno FIN_DE_ARCHIVO
fin

token = lexer()
mientras token != FIN_DE_ARCHIVO
    elegir (token)
        caso NUMERO:
            poner("Numero")
            romper
        caso SUMA:
            poner("Suma")
            romper
        caso RESTA:
            poner("Resta")
            romper
        caso MULTIPLICACION:
            poner("Multiplicacion")
            romper
        caso DIVISION:
            poner("Division")
            romper
        caso MODULO:
            poner("Modulo")
            romper
        caso POTENCIA:
            poner("Potencia")
            romper
        caso PARENTESIS_IZQ:
            poner("Parentesis Izquierdo")
            romper
        caso PARENTESIS_DER:
            poner("Parentesis Derecho")
            romper
        caso FIN_DE_LINEA:
            poner("Fin de Linea")
            romper
        caso ERROR:
            poner("Error")
            romper
        defecto:
            romper
    fin
    token = lexer()
fin

escribir("Se leyeron "..caracteres_leidos.." caracteres")

sis.salir()

El problema radica en el caso dentro del mientras.
Me da el siguiente error syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFICADOR, expecting NUMERICO or CADENA.
Ya intenté resolverlo convirtiendo a todo los tipos de datos nativos, pero no resulto.
Espero que alguien pueda decirme como solucionarlo.

Ni sabia ni que existia este lenguaje. Al margen de eso, lo que veo es que en la condición elegir de la función lexer te estaría faltando agregar un defecto.

Sí tengo el defecto.

@Marcos Ya lo resolví, gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.

Ya lo resolví.
Cambié las constantes por su valor numérico y al parecer me faltó ponerle un fin a una condicional.
Aquí dejo el código funcional.
limpiar()
funcion fibonacci(n)
    retorno mate.redondear(((((1 + mate.raiz(5)) / 2) ^ n) - (((1 - mate.raiz(5)) / 2) ^ n)) / mate.raiz(5))
fin
poner(fibonacci(1000))
NUMERO = 0
SUMA = 1
RESTA = 2
MULTIPLICACION = 3
DIVISION = 4
MODULO = 5
POTENCIA = 6
PARENTESIS_IZQ = 7
PARENTESIS_DER = 8
FIN_DE_ARCHIVO = 9
FIN_DE_LINEA = 10
ERROR = 11

caracteres_leidos = 0

automata = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 0, 14, 15],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
]

alfabeto = [
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '^', ' ', '\t', '\n' 
]

TAM_ALFABETO = lista.longitud(alfabeto)
CANTIDAD_DE_ESTADOS = 16

funcion columna(c)
    desde (i = 0; i < TAM_ALFABETO; i++)
        si c == alfabeto[i]
            retorno i
        fin
    fin
fin

funcion lexer()
    c = leer()
    estado = 0
    desde (i = 0; i <= cadena.longitud(c); i++)
        caracteres_leidos = i
        estado = automata[estado][columna(c)]
        elegir (estado)
            caso 4:
                retorno NUMERO
            caso 5:
                retorno ERROR
            caso 6:
                retorno PARENTESIS_IZQ
            caso 7:
                retorno PARENTESIS_DER
            caso 8:
                retorno SUMA
            caso 9:
                retorno RESTA
            caso 10:
                retorno MULTIPLICACION
            caso 11:
                retorno DIVISION
            caso 12:
                retorno MODULO
            caso 13:
                retorno POTENCIA
            caso 14:
                retorno FIN_DE_LINEA
            caso 15:
                retorno ERROR
        fin
    fin
    retorno FIN_DE_ARCHIVO
fin

token = FIN_DE_ARCHIVO//= lexer()
mientras token != FIN_DE_ARCHIVO
    elegir (token)
        caso 0:
            poner("Numero")
            romper
        caso 1:
            poner("Suma")
            romper
        caso 2:
            poner("Resta")
            romper
        caso 3:
            poner("Multiplicacion")
            romper
        caso 4:
            poner("Division")
            romper
        caso 5:
            poner("Modulo")
            romper
        caso 6:
            poner("Potencia")
            romper
        caso 7:
            poner("Parentesis Izquierdo")
            romper
        caso 8:
            poner("Parentesis Derecho")
            romper
        caso 10:
            poner("Fin de Linea")
            romper
        caso 11:
            poner("Error")
            romper
        defecto:
            romper
    fin
fin
escribir("Se leyeron "..caracteres_leidos.." caracteres")

sis.salir()

Aún me falta completar el analizador, pero ya funciona el código.
